# How to get userDetailsService in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

Hi i tried to get *userDetailsService* with *InMemoryDao*. But i can't get it, i tried *@Autowired*, @Inject (*UserDetailsService*, *InMemoryDaoImpl*, *InMemoryManager*...) but cant get this working.

Have **public class Security  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** and **public class GlobalSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.**

Tried with only WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with all four *@Enable*...
Can some help me to solve this, i need to use *loadUserByUsername*()?

Answer (score 2):

You can expose the `userDetailsService` bean by overriding method `userDetailsServiceBean()` in your configuration class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. The whole method will look like this:

```
@Bean(name = "myUserDetailsService")
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
    return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
}
```

And then you can inject it for example with @Autowired.

Comment: Thank you, this is true... But i can't get _@Autowired_ or _@Injected_, no matter what i tried. 
My class:
_@ComponentScan_
_@Configurable_
public class AuthenticationBroker extends BrokerFilter implements Broker is not checked for injection. 

I tried both autowiring field and setter, setter method is not called, but Bean with name userDetailsService is created. Below is console print
 
2014-08-10 02:18:46.102  INFO 3636 ...AbstractConnector...Started SelectChannelConnector 0.0.0.0:8080
userDetailsService...
user

Did you know why my class is not checked?
I solved this by using static class.

Comment: Is your Application class (extends SpringBootServletInitializer) annotated with @ComponentScan?

Comment: Yes, same with and without extends SpringBootServletInitializer... I cant get this working in this way. I solved this problem by, creating static class and setting userDetailsService and then using in my class getUserDetailsService from static class. Also i can getBean("userDetailsService"), only thing what is not clear is why spring dont check this class for _@Autowired_ or _@Inject_ :S